# Unable to draw a line in android using views

Tags: android, view

This is the java part of the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    class surf extends View {

        public surf(Context c,AttributeSet as) {
            super(c,as);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            canvas.drawLine(20, 20,200, 20,p);
        }
    }
}
```

And the resource file for the same without other views

```
 <view
    class="tictac.Tictac.MainActivity$surf"
    android:id="@+id/graphics" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It closes as soon as it opens with a error, I have been following the tutorial in the android website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Here I am adding own view as main view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new surf(this));
    }

    class surf extends View {

        public surf(Context c)
        {
            super(c);
        }

        public surf(Context c,AttributeSet as) {
            super(c,as);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            canvas.drawLine(20, 20,200, 20,p);
        }
   }
}
```

Or you can add your view in XML

```
<com.my.package.MyClass
    android:id="@+id/graphics" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```